# Trying to add a feature to a Chrome Extension that will prevent scmplayer from autoplaying on page visits

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension using JavaScript and jQuery, and among other things, I'd like it to prevent scmplayer from autoplaying on pages visited by the user. The following represents a typical addition of scmplayer to a page, with the autoplay setting enabled:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://scmplayer.net/script.js"
    data-config="{
        'skin':'skins/cyber/skin.css',
        'volume':50,
        'autoplay':true, <!-- The autoplay setting -->
        'shuffle':true,
        'repeat':1,
        'placement':'top',
        'showplaylist':false,
        'playlist':[{'title':'Bauhaus, %22Antonin Artaud%22','url':'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VJS9SKz7yog'},
        ...
        ">
</script>
```

I think I should approach this by editing the script's data-config attribute before the script has a chance to run, changing `'autoplay':true` to '`autoplay':false`.

How do I do that bit with jQuery or Javascript?

Then, is there a particularly good way to modify this script's data-config attribute from within a Chrome extension? Or, if there's a better way to prevent scmplayer from autoplaying, how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SCM API](http://scmplayer.net/#addons) to pause/stop before starting like this,

```
SCM.pause();
```

`SCM` is a global scope variable here.

But chrome extension's content scripts are executed in an isolated environment, so you can't directly access this varible from your extension content.js.

You must inject a javascript code to page.

Here is my extension files,

### content.js

```
var actualCode = '(' + function() {
    function stopScm() {
        try {
            SCM.pause();
            alert("scm player was stopped");
        } catch(e) { 
            setTimeout(stopScm, 1000);
        }
    }
    stopScm();
} + ')();';
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = actualCode;
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
```

### manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Stops SCM player",
  "version": "0.2",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Example",
  "permissions": [
    "http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39457223/bountify/16/"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [ {
       "matches": ["http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39457223/bountify/16/*"],
       "js": ["content.js"],
       "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ] 
}
```

- [Here is the packed extension file (.crx)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39457223/bountify/16/stopScm.crx)
- [Here is the demo page that extension runs on](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39457223/bountify/16/1.html)

### EDIT:

After you had shared that url, I tried my extension on that one.
Yes it wasn't working.

The problem is that extension code runs before `scmframe` is loaded.

`scmframe` is the static id of `<iframe>` that is appended by SCM script.

So waiting for iframe to be loaded would be better, try this content script, It's also working on your URL.

### content.js

```
$("#scmframe").load(function() {
    var actualCode = '(' + function() {
        function stopScm() {
            try {
                SCM.pause();
            } catch(e) {
                setTimeout(stopScm(), 1000);
            }
        }
        stopScm();
    } + ')();';
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.textContent = actualCode;
    (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
    script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Need to attend to another issue right now but will test as soon as I can.

Comment: Oops. Throws this error: "Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".

Comment: @user1452893, I've just made an example, it's working. Can I see you `manifest.json` or your extension if it's possible?

Comment: I got rid of that error by adding "web_accessible_resources": ["content.js"] to my manifest. Unfortunately, I can show my extension at present time. But, I created the content.js exactly as you have and modified the manifest but it is still not working. Can you show your example?

Comment: @user1452893, Ok, I've updated my answer by including `.crx file` and demo page. And you can see the `manifest.json` below.

Comment: Sorry, I changed demo page link.

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly on your demo page. But, I cannot get it to work on a [blog page like this one](http://blackbladesbook.tumblr.com/)

Comment: I think the "all_frames" needs to be enabled. Will try that.

Comment: That's the ticket. Thanks!